# Can multiple 40k psykers cast the same spell in the same phase?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I really enjoy psykers, and I've built a Tyranid army that is pretty psyker heavy. This question is for 8th edition rules for Warhammer 40k.

The friends I play with, are trying to tell me that once a single power (other than smite) is manifested, that power itself cannot be manifested again in that turn. With multiple units that are capable of knowing multiple powers, this seems like a problem.

I'm currently running with:

- A Swarmlord which knows Smite **plus two other powers**
- a Broodlord which knows Smite **plus one other power**
- a Tervigon which knows Smite **plus one other power**
- a Neurothrope which knows Smite **plus one other power**
- a unit of Zoanthropes which know Smite **plus one other power**

Since the Hive Mind Discipline psychic list has 6 powers, if this is true, then I can at least cover them all and not have to worry about overlap. But if I get another psyker unit or character, then I'm in trouble.

The closest mention I can find in the rulebook is in the Psychic Phase on pg. 178:

> A psyker cannot attempt to manifest the same psychic power more than once in a turn.

This sounds like a single psyker unit or character just can't cast the same spell itself. **Can different units or characters cast the same psychic power in the same phase?**

Comment: Either your friends are confused, or they don't want you to use your unit's abilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've found out where the rule is in the book. The rule is found under the Matched Play Mission Rules, found at the bottom of page 215.

Psychic Focus

> With the exception of Smite, each psychic power can be attempted only once per turn, rather than once per psyker per turn.

So this only applies to Matched Play, involving point limits and restrictions for organized events or tournament play. If you're playing Open or Narrative play matches, this does not apply.

Comment: There's also a rule (though it may be a Beta rule, certainly it's used in tournaments) that if you attempt smite multiple times in a turn, it's one harder to manifest each time. So first smite requires a 5, second a 6, and so on.

Comment: I've been wanting to find where that rule is too. So you know exactly where that rule is?

Comment: [2018 FAQ](https://whc-cdn.games-workshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/warhammer_40000_The_Big_FAQ_1_2018_en.pdf)